# Find the total distance traveled by a particle between $t = 1$ and $t = 3$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, vectors

I was looking through some [AP Calculus BC problems](https://secure-media.collegeboard.org/digitalServices/pdf/ap/sample-questions-ap-calculus-ab-and-bc-exams.pdf) provided by The College Board, and I came across this one:

> At time $t \geq 0$, a particle moving in the *xy*-plane has velocity vector given by $v(t) = \langle4e^{-t}, \sin(1+\sqrt{t})\rangle$. What is the total distance the particle travels between $t = 1$ and $t = 3$?

I used an integral of the magnitude of the velocity vector like so:

$$\int_{1}^{3}||v(t)||\,\mathrm dt= \int_{1}^{3} \sqrt{\left(-4e^{-t}\right)^{2}+\left(\dfrac{\cos(1+\sqrt{t})}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)^{2}}\,\mathrm dt \approx 1.403$$

But the only choices are $1.861$, $1.983$, $2.236$, and $4.851$, and the correct answer is supposed to be $1.861$. I've checked to make sure I've differentiated correctly and that I've calculated correctly. Is there something wrong with how I calculated the total distance?

Comment: You already have $v(t)$, there is no need to differentiate it.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout Oh! Duh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\int_{1}^{3}||v(t)||dt= \int_{1}^{3} \sqrt{4e^{-2t}+\sin^2(1+\sqrt{t})}dt$$

Comment: Man, I didn't realize that I'd treated it as a position vector.

Comment: @AndrewLi Yes indeed usually s(t) is given!